# Unexpected commands in Eclipse RCP application Quick Access?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have five command extension points (org.eclipse.ui.commands). They all have handler extension points (org.eclipse.ui.handlers). Two of them launch two different view extension points (org.eclipse.ui.views). They show up in the "Quick Access" box as intended. The three others are different commands to launch the same editor extension point (org.eclipse.ui.editors). For some reason, two of these other commands unexpectedly appear in the QA box. It was a fluke that I even noticed it as this was unintended behaviour. I am at a loss as to explain how two of them show, but the other does not. I would like to ensure none of these three editor commands appear in the QA box. Please advise.

Comment: Why do you think they should not appear? All commands which can execute appear in the Quick Access list.

Comment: @greg-449 Because the user should not have access to them. Two of the commands are acceptable, the other three are not. One could ask the reverse question. Why should all commands automatically appear in the QA box? Regardless, they do not because one of my commands does not appear. Why is that?

Comment: As I said the code `org.eclipse.ui.internal.quickaccess.CommandProvider` includes all commands as long as they can currently be executed. So presumably that one command cannot be executed.

Comment: @greg-449 But WHY is one not executable and the others are? All five commands are practically clones of each other. I cannot find the differentiating factor. Hence my SO question. Give me lead. Anything. Make a helpful suggestion.